# What gems do you recommend to use for this kind of automation?

Tags: ruby, command-line, rubygems, automation, nginx

I have to create a script to manage maintenance pages server for my hosting company.

I will need to do a CLI interface that would act like this (example scenario) :

(here, let's suppose that mcli is the name of the script, 1.1.1.1 the original server address (that host the website, www.exemple.com)

Here I just create the loopback interface on the maintenance server with the original ip address and create the nginx site-specific config file in sites-enabled

```
$ mcli register www.exemple.com 1.1.1.1
[DEBUG] Adding IP 1.1.1.1 to new loopback interface lo:001001001001
[WARNING] No root directory specified, setting default maintenance page.
[DEBUG] Registering www.exemple.com maintenance page and reloading Nginx: OK
```

Then when I want to enable the maintenance page and completely shutdown the website:

```
$ mcli maintenance www.exemple.com
[DEBUG] Connecting to router with SSH: OK
[DEBUG] Setting new route to 1.1.1.1 to maintenance server: OK
[DEBUG] Writing configuration: Ok
```

Then removing the maintenance page:

```
$ mcli nomaintenance www.exemple.com
[DEBUG] Connecting to router with SSH: OK
[DEBUG] Removing route to 1.1.1.1: Ok
[DEBUG] Writing configuration: Ok
```

And I would need a function to see the actual states of the websites

```
$ mcli list
+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Site Name        | Server I.P      | Maintenance mode |
+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| www.example.com  | 1.1.1.1         | Enabled          |
| www.example.org  | 1.1.1.2         | Disabled         |
+------------------+-----------------+------------------+

$ mcli show www.example.org
Site Name:        www.example.org
Server I.P:       1.1.1.1
Maintenance Mode: Enabled
Root Directory :  /var/www/maintenance/default/
```

But I never did this kind of scripting with Ruby. What gems do you recommend for this kind of things ? For command line parsing ? Column/Colorized output ? SSH connection (needed to connect to cisco routers)

Do you recommend me to use a local database (sqlite) to store meta datas (Stages changes, actual states) or do you recommend me to compute on the fly by analyzing nginx/interfaces configuration files and using syslog for monitoring changes done with this script ?

This script will be used at first time for a massive datacenter physical migration, and next for standard usages for scheduled downtimes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend you get a copy of [Build awesome command-line applications in Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/dccar/build-awesome-command-line-applications-in-ruby).

That said, you might want to check

- [GLI](http://davetron5000.github.com/gli/classes/GLI.html) command line parsing like git
- [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) command line parsing

Personally, I'd go for the SQLite approach for storing data, but I'm biased (having a strong SQL background).

Comment: Doing SQL is not a problem for me. The thing that could be a problem is the synchronization of the "real" state, and the states in the database, to be sure the database is not stale. But maybe I could use the database just for logging changes and site registration (name->IP), and getting the real state from running configuration

Answer (score 0):

Thor is a good gem for handling CLI options.  It allows this type of organization in your script:

```
class Maintenance < Thor
  desc "maintenance", "put up maintenance page"
  method_option :switch, :aliases => '-s', :type => 'string'
  #The method name is the name of the task that would be run   => mcli maintenance
  def maintenance
    #do stuff
  end

  no_tasks do
    #methods that you don't want cli tasks for go here
  end
end
Maintenance.start
```

I don't really have any good suggestions for column/colorized output though.

I definitely recommend using some kind of a database to store states though.  Maybe not sqlite, I would probably opt for maybe a redis database that stores key/value pairs with the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We have similar task. I use next architecture

- Small application (C) what generate config file
- Add nginx init.d script new switch update_clusters. This script will restart nginx only if config file is changed

```
update_clusters() {
   ${CONF_GEN} --outfile=/tmp/nginx_clusters.conf
   RETVAL=$?            
   if [[ "$RETVAL" !=  "0" ]]; then
     return 5
   fi
   if ! diff ${CLUSTER_CONF_FILE} /tmp/nginx_clusters.conf > /dev/null; then
       echo "Cluster configuration changed. Reload service"
       mv -f /tmp/nginx_clusters.conf ${CLUSTER_CONF_FILE}
       reload
   fi                   
}
```

- Set of bash scripts to add records to database.
- Web console to add/modify/delete records in database (extjs+nginx module)